# Objective-C: Parsing XML with gdata

Tags: objective-c, xml-parsing, gdata

I'm trying to parse a huge xml document (describing  3d model) with GdataxmlNode objective-c library.

Here is a sample of XML that blocks me :

```
<library_effects>
    <effect name="Love_Love-fx" id="Love_Love-fx">
        <profile_COMMON>
            <newparam sid="sexy-surface">
                <surface type="2D">
                    <init_from>sexy</init_from>
                    <format>A8R8G8B8</format>
                </surface>
            </newparam>
            ....
        </profile_COMMON>
    </effect>
    ....
</library_effects>
```

**My objective** :

1. get the effect name (*Love_Love-fx*) : works perfect
2. get the content of init_from (*sexy*) : doesn't work at all

Here is how I parse it :

```
xmlGetData = [xmlDoc.rootElement elementsForName:@"library_effects"];   

//Effects infos
int eff_c;
NSMutableArray *eff_ids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  //effect names
NSMutableArray *eff_src = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  //efects sources

for (GDataXMLElement *e in xmlGetData)
{
    eff_c = [[e elementsForName:@"effect"]count];        
    NSArray *eff_node  = [e elementsForName:@"effect"];
    for (int i = 0; i < eff_c; i++)
    {
        //get the effect name (id & name are the same)
        [eff_ids addObject:[[eff_node objectAtIndex:i]attributeForName:@"id"]];
        //get the content of init_from
        [eff_src addObject:[[eff_node objectAtIndex:i]elementForName:@"init_from"]];
    }
}
```

**My problem** : 
I have a SIGABRT on last line (`[eff_src addObject.........`) so I don't manage to get the content of "init_from"

(because `[[eff_node objectAtIndex:i]elementForName:@"init_from"]]` returns Nil. ?)

Could someone help me please?
(Is there any clear & complete documentation ? I only saw blog post explaining a part of it)

**Disgusting solution** :
Using `[[[[[[eff_node objectAtIndex:i]childAtIndex:0]childAtIndex:0]childAtIndex:0]childAtIndex:0]stri‌​ngValue];`

Answer (score 1):

`eff_node` is the XML node `effect`.  My guess is that the `elementForName:` method does not work recursively and is returning nil because `init_from` is not an immediate child of `effect`.

Either that, or you have `effect`s in your XML that do not have `init_from` nodes contained within them.

Basically, you can't add nil to an `NSMutableArray` so you need to test both of your `addObject:` parameters for nil e.g.

```
id idAttr = [[eff_node objectAtIndex:i]attributeForName:@"id"];
if (idAttr != nil)
{
    [eff_ids addObject:idAttr];
}
GDataXMLElement* initFrom = [[eff_node objectAtIndex:i]elementForName:@"init_from"];
if (initFrom != nil)
{
    [eff_src addObject: initFrom];
}
```

Note also that the line

```
NSArray *eff_node  = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

is unnecessarily instantiating an empty array and in manual reference counting world is a memory leak.

---

I've just been looking at the GDataXML API and it is a) undocumented (in the sense that they couldn't be arsed to write documentation, not the sense of a private API) and b) limited.

The method you are using does not do a recursive search, so you have two options, either implement your own recursive search or use the XPath API.  The fillowing should get the nodes you want:

```
 NSError* myError = nil;
 NSArray* initFromNodes = [[eff_node objectAtIndex: i] nodesForXPath: @"//init_from" error: &myError];
```

The `//`part of the XPath means "any number of levels down the tree"

Comment: using your `GDataXMLElement* initFrom = [[eff_node objectAtIndex:i]elementForName:@"init_from"];`
give me initFrom=nil so same problem :x (I didn't add the if() because I need all those info in any cases)

Comment: @IggY You need the `if` because you cannot put `nil` into an `NSArray`.  That's what causes your SIGABRT.  You are either getting nil because the `elementForName:` method doesn't search recursively or because you have elements without `init_from` sub nodes.

Comment: Ok I got why I need the if, sorry it was stupid ^^
However, init_from is ALWAYS =nil :x So How can I bypass the fact that `elementForName` isn't recursive ?

Comment: the only way I found for now is making : `GDataXMLElement* initFrom = [[[[[[eff_node objectAtIndex:i]childAtIndex:0]childAtIndex:0]childAtIndex:0]childAtIndex:0]stringValue];` but is really disgusting :s

Comment: @IggY yes, I've been looking at the code for GDataXML and it seems pretty poor to me in that the functionality is limited and the API is not documented at all.  There is a method to do a search for an XPath though.  I will edit the answer to show this.

Comment: You think I should change my XML Parser ?
(thank you for you help & reactivity btw)

Comment: Method with xPath fill the array with empty strings :x

Comment: @IggY it shouldn't put strings in the array at all, it should put the init_from element in, unless your XML uses name spaces.

Comment: when I print my array whit `NSLog(@"%s", eff_src);` it gives me `(\n), (\n),...` where \n is a newline

Comment: sorry, I did `%@` not `"%s"` :s

Comment: @IggY You need to check the objects in a debugger to see what they are

Comment: _NSCFString and many other pointer, nothing possible to read by human in the object :s When i'm accessing it from my childrenAtIndex cascade, I get readable data.
My XML is huge, do i need to change my parser? I prefer not so do you see any easy way to manage this kind of case ? (I have many others in my code and some are much more complicated ;x)